# Adding navigational links in jsp?

Tags: jsp, web-applications, servlets, struts, jstl

I have made a Struts project (Struts2) with some basic pages such as `Login.jsp`, `Main.jsp` etc.

I have done the navigation in this manner, is there a better way to do it ?

Added a List holding the url paths as an attribute in the session (Done in the servlet/action class)

```
private void initNavigationMenu(){
    navigationMenu = new HashMap<String, String>();
    navigationMenu.put("Main", "/main.jsp");
    navigationMenu.put("Login", "/login.jsp");
    navigationMenu.put("Registration", "/registration.jsp");
}

@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
    initNavigationMenu();
    event.getServletContext().setAttribute("menu", navigationMenu);

}
```

In the JSP page I am comparing the strings

```
<div id="nav_container">
    <ul id="nav">
        <c:forEach items="${menu}" var="item">
            <c:choose>
                <c:when test="${pageContext.request.servletPath == item.value}">
                  <li><a id="nav_active" href="" style="color: #000000">${item.key}</a> </li>
                </c:when>
                <c:otherwise>
                  <b>
                  <li><a href="/projectname${item.value}">${item.key}</a></li>
                  </b>
                </c:otherwise>
            </c:choose>
        </c:forEach>
    </ul>                   
</div>
```

Definitely there is a better way to do this, can someone suggest me the right way to implement.

Comment: You create a list of link URLs and text and display them.

Comment: I would not use a `HashMap` because it's unordered. It would be better to use a [`LinkedHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)

Comment: Also, using [`<c:url>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnakh.html#bnakn) would be better to create links.

Answer (score 0):

Assume `navigationMenu` object contains action paths. Then in each action you generate a page object just as getting reference to menu items and put this object into request. So, it would be available via `${page}`.

And when you render the JSP page you know what a page object is present instead of comparing strings of `servletPath`.

If you required to manage persistent page objects this better done with the most of CMS. Some CMS even use unique page id as parameter in the URL to reference the page they are showing. But it's not necessary. All you need is just the page object that reference to an action path.